# Styling option_ui and browser_action page for Firefox Mobile

Tags: css, firefox-addon, media-queries

I developed an extension for Firefox with an **option popup** for preferences.

On mobile, as it doesn't open as a popup but as a new tab `moz-extension://(...)/popup.html`, I had to apply some specific CSS media queries.

But as you can see below, it's definitely not working.

What should I do ?

CSS page is here https://github.com/ANN-MB/LEIA/blob/master/extension%20firefox/leia.css

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing any media queries in the CSS you provided.

Comment: Sorry I removed it in the last version because it was inefficient. But still looking for a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

It wasn't about **media queries** but because my `manifest.json` looked like this :

```
"options_ui": {
    "page": "config.html",
    "browser_style": false,
    "open_in_tab": true
  }
```

It seems that when `open_in_tab` is set to **true**, the Firefox Mobile Browser opens the **option page** with the desktop display (don't ask me why).

So turning "open_in_tab" to **false** gave me the good render.

Answer (score 0):

But you need @media querys for wanted solutions! Your Medium is provide an max range of size, you only need is to declare your style on diffents sizeranges:

```
@media(min-width:XXXpx) {
    // your style here
}
```

for more information take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488

Comment: Already did that but wasn't working. I erased them all. I'd like an idea to keep fonts and `<select>` tags full page, as I showed in my example :)

Comment: OK, can you post your not working media query´s please? Did you add your custom css code as last of all styles? Otherwise it can be overwritten by other stylesheets. Also sometimes can help "!important" e.g.: `@media(min-width:XXXpx) {
    .your-class {with:80%!important;}
}`